# Why can't I call a method with parameter `this` in a class extending a generic trait?

Tags: scala, generics, traits

I'm writing a trait to describe node-like objects in a Hierarchical structure (like a graph). My working code is below:

```
trait Hierarchical[T <: Hierarchical[_]] {
  // The parents will be a list of some arbitrary Hierarchical
  val parents: List[Hierarchical[_]] = Nil
  var children: List[Hierarchical[T]] = List()

  def addChild(child: Hierarchical[T]): Unit = {
    children ++= List(child)
  }
}

abstract class NonRootNode(override val parents: List[Hierarchical[_]])
  extends Hierarchical[NonRootNode] {
}

abstract class RootNode extends Hierarchical[NonRootNode] {
  final override val parents = Nil
}
```

I have some tests which reflect this behavior:

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

class DummyRoot extends RootNode
class DummyNonRoot(override val parents: List[DummyRoot]) 
  extends NonRootNode(parents)

class TestUtil extends FlatSpec {

  "A RootNode" should "not have parents" in {
    val dummyRoot = new DummyRoot
    assert(dummyRoot.parents.isEmpty)
  }

  "A NonRootNode" should "have parents when constructed with them" in {
    val dummyRoot = new DummyRoot
    assert(dummyRoot.parents.isEmpty)
    val dummyNonRoot = new DummyNonRoot(List(dummyRoot))
    dummyRoot.addChild(dummyNonRoot)
    assert(dummyNonRoot.parents.contains(dummyRoot))
    assert(dummyRoot.children.contains(dummyNonRoot))
  }    
}
```

However, I find the API to be a bit unwieldy in the second test. I shouldn't need to add a child to the root node explicitly since I've already specified the child's parents. I'd like to remove this from the public API, so my thought is to modify `NonRootNode`'s constructor behavior to call this for each of the parents. Specifically, I want to write:

```
abstract class NonRootNode(override val parents: List[Hierarchical[_]])
  extends Hierarchical[NonRootNode] {

  //for each parent, add `this` to its children
  parents.map{p=>p.addChild(this)}
}
```

However, when I add this line, I get the following error:

```
Error:(19, 29) type mismatch;
 found   : NonRootNode
 required: Hierarchical[_$3]
  parents.map{p=>p.addChild(this)}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I'm getting this compiler error. My understanding of `Hierarchical[_]` is *any `Hierarchical`*, but I could be mistaken. In any case, I think I'm close to my desired behavior. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How can the parents be any `Hierarchical` while the children are `Hierarchical[T]`?

Comment: @Jasper-M Because parents can be `RootNode`s or `NonRootNode`s (or any other extension of `Hierarchical`). Children will all be of the same type such that they are `Hierarchical`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Hierarchical[_]` does NOT mean "any Hierarchical". It means "a Hierarchical of some fixed type, that is unknown".

For example

```
def foo: Hierarchical[_] = new Hierarchical[Int]
```

works: it declares a function, that will return some implementation of `Hierarchical`, exact type of which is not known to the caller. This is fine.

On the other hand:

```
def bar(h: Hierarchical[String]) = doStuff(h)
bar(foo)
```

Does *not* work: function `bar` wants a parameter of an exact type `Hierarchical[String]`, and what is passed to it can not be guaranteed to have that type, it's type parameter is unknown.

In your case, `.addChild` is a method of `Hierarchical[T]` (where the value of `T` is unknown to you), and wants a parameter of the same type . But what you are passing to it is `Hierarchical[NonRootNode]`. This is illegal, because there is no way to guarantee that `NonRootNode` will be the same as the (unknown) `T`.

Comment: Interesting -- makes sense. Is there an easy way to achieve my behavior? I've tried adding an extra type parameter, but found myself in a mutual recursion situation, which became a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Well, I am not sure, what exactly you actually mean by "my behavior" here.
Your example is not sufficient to deduce that, because, judging by it, there is no reason for the `Hierarchical` to be parametrized at all :/

Comment: So that may be the answer -- parameterization is unnecessary. Will update tests and report back soon.

Comment: And indeed there is no need for parameterization. Thanks a lot!